# Is there a way to prevent springboot aplications to try to describe topics for which they have no permission

Tags: apache-kafka, acl, describe

I want to remove a generic ACL that never should have been created, that allows all kafka principals to describe all topics on the cluster. However, after this is done, springboot kafka client applications using their kafka principals still issue describe requests for all of them, and get denied. This happens only when they start, but still I want to avoid that, because it floods the log, and I am not sure what impact does it have on them, but I believe probably none. How do they do it? Is the information about all the topics created on cluster somehow cached on the client side, or is there an api command to issue such a request that returns them a list of all topics, even those for which they do not have a specific ACL that allows them to describe that topic? How can I prevent them from doing this?